# How does JavaScriptCore engine know an object has no references?

Tags: javascript, memory-management

In JavascriptCore engine, when it starts garbage collection, it will clear an unreferenced object, but i can't find any reference count mechanism for this object. 
   for example:

```
var v1 = new Object(); 
var v2 = v1; 
v1 = null; // have reference, object won't be collected.
v2 = null; // have no reference, object will be collected.
```

When I read JavaScriptCore source code, I didn't find any code to record the reference count, so how JSC know the reference count of an object?

Comment: Reference counting isn't the only way to do garbage collection. Look up "mark sweep garbage collection", that's another common algorithm.

Comment: But how JSC know a block with an object is not alive and need to sweep?

Comment: By scanning memory and determining that it's not reachable from anywhere.

Comment: JSC uses a generational garbage collector. Read about this here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2009/03/02/back-to-basics-generational-garbage-collection.aspx